# How to get the sum of all elements in a scrollable listview column in android?

Tags: android, listview

Please help to get the sum of all elements of a scrollable list view.
I have tried all the methods mentioned here..when the scrolling happens the views are recycled and new values enter in to the loop and adding with the existing...so the total value is growing up like anything.

Comment: Can you post the code which is the closest you've come to a solution?

Comment: sum of what  Visible elements or nonvisible?